# How many actions should Django view process?

Tags: django-views

I looked through the Django built-in Auth app and noticed that views are split in many like:

`password_reset`,
`password_reset_confirm`,
`password_reset_done`,
`password_reset_complete`

Here every simple action has a distinct view. Should all the apps be written like that or is it fine for one view to manage more URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule of thumb is that different URLs should be handled by different views.

Prior to the introduction of [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) in Django 1.3, this could lead to a mess if your view function tried to handle many cases. But now you can create class-based views which allow you to subclass existing views and reuse behaviour of those views.

For example (for a site that has multiple games).

```
class GameView(View):

    def game_method(self):
        # compute things here            
        return data

class PuzzleGameView(GameView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = self.game_method()
        # do other things here
        return HttpResponse("")

class SudokuGameView(PuzzleGameView):
    pass

class ActionGameView(GameView):
    pass
```

Methods defined in `GameView` can be called and reused in subclasses.

Comment: Can you make an example how to render PuzzleGameView then with some data processing in get method? I can't get it working.

Comment: I've added a few methods to the views but I'm not sure what you mean exactly. When you have a hierarchy of views and subclasses, you can call methods of parent classses as you wish.